# Memory Error unable to allocate array.shape

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm using python language.
I'm training my data set which has roughly 9000 images. Im using pre-trained neural network VGG16.
 Now the issue is that memory error: Unable to allocate array with shape (500,500,3) and data type unit 32

I have tried float 64, 32, 16,8 but memory error is the same 
what should i do to handle this error. As well data parallelism using data gen  function of keras but it seems i'm doing something wrong

Libraries

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.applications import VGG16
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import Image
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import optimizers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
img_rows, img_cols = 500,500
channels=3
def load_labels(myDir):
    labels=[]
    fileList = glob.glob(myDir)
    for fname in fileList:
        fileName = os.path.basename(fname)
        curLabel = fileName.split("_")[0]
        labels.append(curLabel)
    return np.asarray(labels)    
def load_dataThreeChannel(myDir):
    images=[]
    fileList = glob.glob(myDir)    
  #  x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)).flatten() for fname in fileList])
  #  x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in fileList])
    for fname in fileList:
        #print(fname)
        img = Image.open(fname)
        output = np.array(img.resize((img_rows,img_cols), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        #output = np.stack((output,)*3, -1)
        images.append(output)  
    x=np.asarray(images)
    print(x.shape)
    return x
myDir ="train_patches/*.png"
labels = load_labels(myDir)
data = load_dataThreeChannel(myDir)
#data = load_data(myDir)
# Data gen to avoid memory error
# create a data generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
# load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory("train_patches/*.png", class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)
# confirm the iterator works
batchX, batchy = train_it.next()
print('Batch shape=%s, min=%.3f, max=%.3f' % (batchX.shape, batchX.min(), batchX.max()))

#Include_top=False, Does not load the last two fully connected layers which act as the classifier.
#We are just loading the convolutional layers. 
vgg_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(img_rows,img_cols,3))

# freeze the layer except the last 4 layers
for layer in vgg_conv.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable=False
num_classes=10
model = Sequential() 
# Add the vgg convolutional base model
model.add(vgg_conv) 
# Add new layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
 # Show a summary of the model. Check the number of trainable parameters
model.summary()    
epochs = 3
X_train = data
Y_train =labels
#X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(data,labels, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32', copy= False)
#X_test = X_test.astype('float32', copy= False)
X_train /= 255
#X_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
#print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
#Y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes)
# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])
# Train the model
history = model.fit(
      X_train,Y_train,
      epochs=10,
      verbose=1)
acc = history.history['acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
epochs = range(len(acc))
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'b', label='Training acc')
plt.title('Training accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
model_json = model.to_json()
open('imdata.json','w').write(model_json)
model.save_weights('imdata.h5',overwrite=True)
```

Please kindly help me with this error. and also  please explain about the imdata.h5 file as well as imdata_json file.

Comment: Shouldn't `w = 0` be inside the first for loop?

Comment: @HansHirse Please kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to load the entire ImgNet dataset into memory, as marked.

```
    def load_dataThreeChannel(myDir):
    images=[]
    fileList = glob.glob(myDir)    
  #  x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)).flatten() for fname in fileList])
  #  x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in fileList])
    for fname in fileList:
        #print(fname)
        img = Image.open(fname) # <-- Load image into memory
        output = np.array(img.resize((img_rows,img_cols), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        #output = np.stack((output,)*3, -1) 
        images.append(output)  # <-- Append the image into the list
    x=np.asarray(images) 
    print(x.shape)
    return x
myDir ="train_patches/*.png"
labels = load_labels(myDir)
data = load_dataThreeChannel(myDir) # <-- HERE
```

Due to its size, you will of course fail. The solution is to load the images on demand, by means of Keras Data Generator - Please see: [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

For your second question - a h5 file may be seen as a large compressed ZIP directory, only instead of ZIP, using the HDF5 compression technology. It may be unpacked with the h5py module. The JSON , I believe, is the identity "tree" of the dataset, relating the names of files to the relevant classes, for example. You can try to load it with the json module (function 'loads') and printing it to see its contents.

Here is a working of example on a different network for the loading of ImgNet:

```
import os
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.applications import mobilenet
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.utils import to_categorical

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# Load MobileNet model
model = MobileNet(weights='imagenet')
opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


# Fetch the dataset directly
imagenet = tfds.image.Imagenet2012()
## or by string name
#imagenet = tfds.builder('imagenet2012')

# Describe the dataset with DatasetInfo
C = imagenet.info.features['label'].num_classes
Ntrain = imagenet.info.splits['train'].num_examples
Nvalidation = imagenet.info.splits['validation'].num_examples
Nbatch = 32
assert C == 1000
assert Ntrain == 1281167
assert Nvalidation == 50000

# Download the data, prepare it, and write it to disk
imagenet.download_and_prepare()

# Load data from disk as tf.data.Datasets
datasets = imagenet.as_dataset()
train_dataset, validation_dataset = datasets['train'], datasets['validation']
assert isinstance(train_dataset, tf.data.Dataset)
assert isinstance(validation_dataset, tf.data.Dataset)

def imagenet_generator(dataset, batch_size=32, num_classes=1000, is_training=False):
  images = np.zeros((batch_size, 224, 224, 3))
  labels = np.zeros((batch_size, num_classes))
  while True:
    count = 0 
    for sample in tfds.as_numpy(dataset):
      image = sample["image"]
      label = sample["label"]

      images[count%batch_size] = mobilenet.preprocess_input(np.expand_dims(cv.resize(image, (224, 224)), 0))
      labels[count%batch_size] = np.expand_dims(to_categorical(label, num_classes=num_classes), 0)

      count += 1
      if (count%batch_size == 0):
        yield images, labels

# Infer on ImageNet
labels = np.zeros((Nvalidation))
pred_labels = np.zeros((Nvalidation, C))
pred_labels_new = np.zeros((Nvalidation, C))

score = model.evaluate_generator(imagenet_generator(validation_dataset,batch_size=32), 
                                  steps= Nvalidation // Nbatch, 
                                  verbose=1)
print("Evaluation Result of Original Model on ImageNet2012: " + str(score))

# Train on ImageNet
checkpoint_path = "Mobilenet/cp-{epoch:04d}.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
os.makedirs(checkpoint_dir, exist_ok=True)

cp_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    checkpoint_path, verbose=1, save_weights_only=True,
    # Save weights, every 1-epoch
    period=1)

csv_logger = keras.callbacks.CSVLogger('MobileNet_training.csv')

print("Starting to train Modified MobileNet...")
epochs = 5

model.fit_generator(imagenet_generator(train_dataset, batch_size=Nbatch, is_training=True),
                        steps_per_epoch= Ntrain // Nbatch,
                        epochs = epochs,
                        validation_data = imagenet_generator(validation_dataset, batch_size=Nbatch),
                        validation_steps = Nvalidation // Nbatch,
                        verbose = 1,
                        callbacks = [cp_callback, csv_logger])

model.save("MobileNet.h5")
```

Comment: I have tried data gen as exhibited in the code but it seems im doing something wrong

Comment: Yes, but that comes later on in your code - you first trying loading the images into memory, and only then supplying them to a generator. The Keras generator I specified receives an image directory, and loads the relevant files only at the forward iterations of the network - It works differently than the standard data generator you are using.

Comment: Should i  use this instead of

Comment: Yes, I recommend it. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Please kindly check is this correct im still getting issues in 3 channels
"""

from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.applications import VGG16
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import Image
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import optimizers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator



img_rows, img_cols = 500,500
channels=3

# def load_labels(myDir):
#     labels=[]
#     fileList = glob.glob(myDir)
#     for fname in fileList:
#         fileName = os.path.basename(fname)
#         curLabel = fileName.split("_")[0]
#         labels.append(curLabel)

#     return np.asarray(labels)   


def load_dataThreeChannel(myDir):
    images=[]
    fileList = glob.glob(myDir)    
  #  x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)).flatten() for fname in fileList])
  #  x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in fileList])
    for fname in fileList:
        #print(fname)
        img = Image.open(fname)
        output = np.array(img.resize((img_rows,img_cols), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        #output = np.stack((output,)*3, -1)
        images.append(output)  
    x=np.asarray(images)
    print(x.shape)
    return x

myDir = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
#included in our dependencies

myDir =myDir.flow_from_directory("C:/Users/iohan/.spyder-py3/IAM/train_patches/", target_size=(224,224), color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True)

Xbatch, Ybatch = myDir.next()

# myDir ="C:/Users/iohan/.spyder-py3/IAM/train_patches/*.png"
# labels = load_labels(myDir)
data = load_dataThreeChannel(myDir)
#data = load_data(myDir)



#Include_top=False, Does not load the last two fully connected layers which act as the classifier.
#We are just loading the convolutional layers. 
vgg_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(img_rows,img_cols,3))

# freeze the layer except the last 4 layers
for layer in vgg_conv.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable=False
num_classes=10
model = Sequential() 
# Add the vgg convolutional base model
model.add(vgg_conv) 
# Add new layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
 # Show a summary of the model. Check the number of trainable parameters
model.summary()    
epochs = 3
X_train = data
Y_train =labels
#X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(data,labels, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32', copy= False)
#X_test = X_test.astype('float32', copy= False)
X_train /= 255
#X_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
#print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')


# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
#Y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes)


# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])
# Train the model
# history = model.fit(
#       X_train,Y_train,
#       epochs=10,
#       verbose=1)

history= step_size_train=myDir.n//myDir.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=myDir,
                   steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                   epochs=10)


acc = history.history['acc']
loss = history.history['loss']


epochs = range(len(acc))

plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'b', label='Training acc')
plt.title('Training accuracy')
plt.legend()


plt.show()


model_json = model.to_json()
open('imdata.json','w').write(model_json)
model.save_weights("C:/Users/iohan/.spyder-py3/IAM/mdata.h5",overwrite=True)
```